# Creating a image dataset

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

I have a folder with 38000 images and I'm trying to create a dataset from them to use in a Convolutional LSTM, which supports input in the format of a 5d array (B,T,W,H,C) where B is the number of samples, T is the size of the samples and the rest of the array are the image properties.

So far I've managed to create a numpy array using the following code:

```
path = input("folder: ")
training_data = []
for img in os.listdir(path):
    pic = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
    pic = cv2.cvtColor(pic,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    pic = cv2.resize(pic,(64,64))
    training_data.append([pic])
np.save(os.path.join(path,'dataset'),np.array(training_data))
```

With this code I can create an array with the shape **(38000, 1, 64, 64, 3)**.

Using as an example data from other datasets such as Moving MNIST I could see that it is an array with the shape **(10000, 20, 64, 64, 1)** which means that it contains 10000 sequences of images each of length 20.

How can I create an array from my data that contains image sequences like Moving MNIST?

To clarify, I need to create an array with my 38000 images divided into sequences of 10 resulting in an array with the shape **(3800, 10, 64, 64, 3)** *- 3800 sequences each of length 10 -*

Comment: You would need to define exactly how the images map into sequences, your question is not clear about that.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy My images are sequential weather radar data, where each image corresponds to an hour and are arranged sequentially within the folder.

I would like to create a sequence for the first 10 hours containing the first 10 images in the folder and so on.

Something like that:

(1-10 images) 1st sequence
(11-20 images) 2nd sequence
...
...
...
(37991-38000 images) last sequence

Comment: you can use `np.reshape(inp, [3800, 10, 64, 64, 3])` to convert 38000 consecutive sequences into batch of 10.